# Button is pressed but php doesn't process

Tags: php

A button is created within a table column by the following code:

```
print("<td> <button type=\"submit\" name=\"Select_Button\" value=\"Submit\"> Update </ button> </td>");
```

I want to check if the button was pressed by:

```
if(isset($_POST['Select_Button']))
{
    print ("Button pressed");
}
```

How ever when i run the code and press the button nothing happens.

Comment: Is the table inside a `<form>`?

Comment: That's too little info and code excerpts. Your last question was about `"Select_Button" . $rowNum`. So an `isset` for the unqualified name wouldn't work of course. (Best not to use `isset` until you have something working and ruled out typos). Use `print_r($_POST)` to see what you actually got.

Comment: When you say "nothing happens", do you mean nothing as in a new page isn't even loaded?

Answer (score 0):

Put else condition as well

```
 if(isset($_POST['Select_Button'])) 
 { 
     print ("Button pressed");
 }
 else
 {
     echo "Unsuccessful";
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="post" action="test1.php" >
<?php
if(isset($_POST['Select_Button']))
{
    print ("Button pressed");
}
print("<td> <button type=\"submit\" name=\"Select_Button\" value=\"Submit\"    `    `> Update </ button> </td>");
?>

</form>
```

Check if form is there or not ?? without form element the button is not working